# Erreur 400 bad Request Actix

Tags: rust, actix-web, rust-diesel

I'm a beginner with rust and i have some troube testing my api.

I try to post some data via curl but keep having error 400 bad Request.

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id": "20", "first_name": "foo1", "last_name": "bar1", "address": "Bourghelles", "mail": "foo1@bar.com", "phone_number": "0620399062"}' http://127.0.0.1:8080/clients -v

```
pub async fn create_clients(pool: web::Data<SqlPool>, req: web::Json<Client>) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
    Ok(web::block(move || clients::create(pool, req))
    .await
    .map(|client| HttpResponse::Ok().json(client))
    .map_err(|_| HttpResponse::InternalServerError())?)
}

#[derive(Queryable, Insertable, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Client {
    pub id: i32,
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
    pub address: String,
    pub mail: String,
    pub phone_number : String,
}

#[derive(Insertable, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[table_name = "clients"]
pub struct NewClient<'a>{
    pub id: i32,
    pub first_name : &'a str,
    pub last_name : &'a str,
    pub address : &'a str,
    pub mail : &'a str,
    pub phone_number  : &'a str,
}

pub fn create(pool: web::Data<SqlPool>, req: web::Json<Client>) -> Result<Client, diesel::result::Error>{
    
    let new_client = NewClient {
        id: req.id,
        first_name: &req.first_name,
        last_name: &req.last_name,
        address: &req.address,
        mail: &req.mail,
        phone_number: &req.phone_number,
    };

    format!{"Hello world from create"};
   
    let conn = pool.get().unwrap();
    use crate::schema::clients::dsl::*;
    let res = diesel::insert_into(clients).values(&new_client).execute(&conn)?;
    return show(pool, 1);
}

async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    
    dotenv().ok();
    
    let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL").expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    let manager = ConnectionManager::<MysqlConnection>::new(database_url);
    let pool = r2d2::Pool::builder()
    .build(manager)
    .expect("Failed to create pool.");

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .data(pool.clone())
            .route("/clients", web::post().to(api::client::create_clients))
            // .service(api::client::hello_world)
            // .service(api::client::all_clients)
            // .service(api::client::find_clients)
            // .service(api::client::update_clients)
            // .service(api::client::delete_clients)
            // .service(api::house::all_houses)
            // .service(api::house::find_houses)
            // .service(api::house::create_houses)
            // .service(api::house::update_houses)
            // .service(api::house::delete_houses)
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is because you input `"id": "20"` and not `"id": 20`

The following test passes:

```
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Client {
    pub id: i32,
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
    pub address: String,
    pub mail: String,
    pub phone_number: String,
}

#[test]
fn deserialize_test() {
    use serde_json::json;
    let client_fail_json = json!(
        {
            "id": "20",
            "first_name": "foo1",
            "last_name": "bar1",
            "address": "Bourghelles",
            "mail": "foo1@bar.com",
            "phone_number": "0620399062"
        }
    );

    let client_fail: Result<Client, _> = serde_json::from_value(client_fail_json);
    assert!(client_fail.is_err());

    let client_json = json!(
        {
            "id": 20,
            "first_name": "foo1",
            "last_name": "bar1",
            "address": "Bourghelles",
            "mail": "foo1@bar.com",
            "phone_number": "0620399062"
        }
    );

    let client: Result<Client, _> = serde_json::from_value(client_json);

    client.unwrap();
}
```